# add days to date smarty

Tags: php, date, smarty

I would like to add the shippingtime of an item in my shop to the current date.
So that I get an availability date.

I tried this but it **doesn't** work:

```
<g:availability_date>
{if $sArticle.shippingtime > 0}
Verfügbar ab:
{assign var="date_now" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
{"$date_now+$Article.shippingtime"|strtotime|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
{/if}
</g:availability_date>
```

But when I just add a few days to the current date then I get a **valid** Output...

```
Verfügbar ab:
{assign var="date_now" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
{"$date_now+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
{/if}
</g:availability_date>
```

Can someone help me with that problem?

Best regards Lukas

Answer (score 0):

It's `$estimated_days + $Article.shippingtime` vs. `$estimated_days + 3 days`.
So what is `$Article.shippingtime`? Despite the question doesn't feature any output,
you're once adding an absolute timestamp and once a relative offset.

Likely you have to convert from absolute timestamp to relative offset first.
"I have to program the whole thing in smarty" sounds meaningless to me,
most commonly one would provide calculated values to the template engine.
It's not even a duty of the controller, but of the underlying model already.
For simple calculations it's still ok in the template, not for complex ones.

Comment: $Article.shippingtime is a variable which is which is provided by Shopware (something like shopify). It Contains a number like 3 or 40 and so on. 

The Output from the second Code snippet is:
<g:availability_date> Verfügbar ab: Sat, 01 Oct 2022 17:17:48 CEST </g:availability_date>

Comment: It is unclear what the input and output is. Or what the expected output should be. While when the one is "working" (whatever that may be) and the other not, I can still point out the difference. Besides, also in PHP adding apples to pears won't work; you might need a relative offset and not an absolute timestamp. And please don't post code into comments, but edit the question.

Comment: The name `$estimated_days` is quite confusing, as it is `$smarty.now`. But one can use that value: `$smarty.now + $offset_in_days * 86400` seconds.

Comment: It's useless to use modifier `|strtotime`, when there's an `integer` value available. In the above code, you're converting the timestamp back and forth, which might only waste electricity as there's no purpose doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust your output tag a bit, PHP can't interpolate the dot notation inside the single quotes. Add braces around `$Article.shippingtime` and add "days" after that.

```smarty
{assign var="estimated_days" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
{"$estimated_days +{$Article.shippingtime} days"|strtotime|date_format:"%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z"}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I don't know why but this solution doesn't work for me...

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly what is in my example? I tested on PHP 7.2 and Smarty 3.1, what versions are you running? What are the exact contents of $Article.shippingtime?